# How can I enable case insensitive autocomplete for a NSComboBox?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've bound the NSComboBox bounded to a data source within interface builder.
I correctly get the autocomplete suggestions, when I type something in the NSComboBox.

However the autocomplete is case sensitive, which means I don't get suggestion if the character uses the wrong case.

How can I enable case insensitive autocomplete for a NSComboBox, which is bound to the data source in interface builder ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement `comboBox:completedString:` in your NSComboBox Data Source, e.g:

```
- (NSString *)comboBox:(NSComboBox *)comboBox completedString:(NSString *)partialString
{
    for (NSString dataString in dataSourceArray) {
        if ([[dataString commonPrefixWithString:partialString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] length] == [commonPrefixWithString:partialString length]) {
            return testItem;
        }
    }
    return @"";
}
```

Comment: But this means I can't specify the data source in interface builder. Correct ? I've many many fields, configured in interface builder, it would be a lot of work to bind them to a data source programmatically.

Comment: @patrik you need to support bindings? (what is the dataSource's type)

Comment: If you're feeding a ComboBox with Cocoa Bindings, you don't have to implement the "required" dataSource methods.  As long as the NSComboBox has a bound controller, you can *also* connect the combo box to a dataSource, and that dataSource only has to have the comboBox:completedString" method implemented.

Comment: @iluvcapra - how do you do that? what's a bound controller? can you write an answer with an example?
this 'completedString' method mentioned - is never getting called.

Comment: what if i'm using an array controller?

Answer (score 5):

you can subclassing an NSComboBoxCell and overriding [NSComboBoxCell completedString:].

```
- (NSString *)completedString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *result = nil;

    if (string == nil)
        return result;

    for (NSString *item in self.objectValues) {
        NSString *truncatedString = [item substringToIndex:MIN(item.length, string.length)];
        if ([truncatedString caseInsensitiveCompare:string] == NSOrderedSame) {
            result = item;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: As I've commented in the other question, self.objectValues is the data source right ? I've bounded all my fields to the data source in interface builder, and I have 80 fields. I should populate them programmatically, in order to customize the autocomplete ?